# Create Word Permutations and Add Their Individual Scores Together (Pandas, Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-itertools

I currently have a df that looks like this:

```
Word     Score    Other
This      10       1
is        10       2    
an        20       5
example   50       3
great     20       2
```

**What I am then doing** is creating permutations based on the words found in the Word column and add up the total score of the words being permutated.   Since my data set is pretty substantial, I want to only create those permutations where the score is above a set total (in this case, 50) in order to limit the sheer total of possible permutations.

Anticipated output:

```
**Permutations**         **Score**
an example                  70
example great               70
This example                60
etc...
```

**Question**  How do I add the score of the permutated words and stack it

The code I have is missing this

```
import itertools
word = exact['Word']
score = exact['Score']
perm = list(itertools.permutations(word, 3))


removal = perm[perm['Score'] >= 50]
```

Any ideas?

EDIT Based on Garret's help:

```
exact = stuff[stuff['Other'] < 6 ]
def find_perms(df, min_score):
    perm = itertools.permutations(df.Word.unique(), 2)
    score = df.Score.to_dict()
    for p in perm:
        s = sum(score[w] for w in p)
        if s >= min_score:
           yield p, s

df = pd.DataFrame(list(find_perms(exact, 50000)),
              columns=['Permutations', 'Score'])
```

Comment: You should make your example dataframe a copy and pastable dictionary. Makes it easy for people to recreate your situation, and provide advice

Comment: I edited the code -- is that what you were thinking?

Comment: No, just something to copy and paste you're original dataframe at the top of your question. Like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25653127/renaming-columns-that-contain-decimal-cell-values

Comment: @DataSwede, that's what pd.read_clipboard() is for... :)

Comment: @Garrett It seems like a fair amount of time it creates the dataframe incorrectly when I use that...

Answer (score 0):

To avoid allocating memory for permutations that don't meet the desired threshold, perhaps compute the score "on-the-fly" before constructing a pandas object?

```
def find_perms(df, min_score):
    perm = itertools.permutations(df.Word.unique(), 2)
    score = df.Score.to_dict()
    for p in perm:
        s = sum(score[w] for w in p)
        if s >= min_score:
            yield p, s

df = pd.DataFrame(list(find_perms(df, 50)),
                  columns=['Permutations', 'Score'])
```

Comment: Ahh, I knew that a yield function would have to be involved -- my question is how do I reference a particular column to be the one that is iterated through?  So in this case, how do I only create permutations from the "word" column while only adding the score column?  Thank you!

Comment: just for further explanation -- this seems to work but it is permutating the index column of the document whereas I need the 'words' column

Comment: ah, updated to pass the `df.Word` column instead of `df.index` to `itertools.permutations()`

Comment: Hey Garrett, I actually tried that and am getting an error -- KeyError: 'This' everytime I run the code.  'This' being the first word in the list below the header 'word'.  I have updated my code above to give a better picture but is this issue caused by the fact that the word list is currently a Pandas Object?

Comment: Here is the partial Traceback: line 70, in find_perms s = sum(score[w] for w in p) ----  KeyError: 'This'

Comment: I'd recommend enabling a debugger and inspecting the value of all the local variables at the point of the fail. If you can provide a full example that reproduces, feel free to