# Renaming columns that contain decimal cell values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'name': ['Bill', np.nan, 'Tony', 'Koli', 'Sally'], 
    'score': [42.32, np.nan, 36.3, 24.522, 73.1], 
    'age': [2, np.nan, 8, 4, 11]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name','score', 'age'])
df
```

I want the name of data['score'] to be changed to data['score_decimal'] if it contains a missing value or a decimal number.

In pseudo-code:

```
for each column in df:
    if column contains np.nan's or decimals:
        then column.name = column.name + '_decimal'
    else:
        do nothing
```

I can make the basic loop but I cannot do the regex search (the "if" line in the loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the missing piece?

```
contains_nan_dec = False
for value in df['score'].unique():
    if value.isdigit() or value is np.nan:
        contains_nan_dec = True
        break
if contains_nan_dec: # pseudocode starts here
    then column.name = column.name + '_decimal'
else:
    do nothing
```

Comment: Is it possible to do: if value.isregex([0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?) or value is np.nan

Comment: I'm not able to tell whether the regex you provided is entirely correct. If it is correct, then of course, you can do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's easier to retrieve the values of each column, perform the check for decimals number or NaN, and then change the column name. First I would create a function to do the check

```
def check(list):
    for elem in list:
        if type(elem) != type('a'):
            if type(elem) == type(1.1) or np.isnan(elem):
                return True
    return False
```

Then I would do something like

```
labels = list(df.columns)

for i in xrange(len(labels)):
    if check(list(df[labels[i]])):
        labels[i] += '_decimal'
df.columns = labels
```

To rename the columns

Comment: Just noticed np.isnan() will not work with str input. So you should add a preliminar check if it is str.

Comment: Won't .isdigit() find both the age (a whole number) column and the score column (a decimal)

Comment: Yes it would, just changed to see if type == float

Comment: Depending of other types you have in dataframe np.isnan might not work, and you should add those formats in the first if, to ensure your code runs

Comment: And apparently you can't directly change an item in df.columns. So let's create a list, manipulate it and then plug in again. Editting

Answer (score 0):

You could do it pretty succinctly like this:

```
float_columns = df.columns[df.dtypes == 'float64']
new_names = {old_name: old_name + '_decimal' for old_name in float_columns}
df = df.rename(columns=new_names)
```

`numpy.nan` is also considered a `float64` so this would cover that case too.